# Why does load(...) return character name of object instead of the object itself?

Tags: r, save, svm

The svm model is created with the package **e1071** in R. To use the model, I need to save it and read as needed.  The package has `write.svm`, but does not have `read.svm`. If I use

```
model <- svm(x, y)

save(model, 'modelfile.rdata')
M <- load('modelfile.rdata')
```

object `M` contains just the word 'model'.

How to save the svm model and read back later, to apply to some new data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the return value for the function `load` in the help file:

> Value:
>
> ```
>  A character vector of the names of objects created, invisibly.
> ```

So "model" is indeed the expected value of `M`. Your svm has been restored under its original name, which is `model`.

If you find it a bit confusing that `load` does not return the object loaded but instead restores it under the name used in saving it, consider using `saveRDS` and `readRDS`.

```
saveRDS(model, 'modelfile.rds')
M <- readRDS('modelfile.rds')
```

and `M` should contain your svm model.

I prefer `saveRDS` and `readRDS` because with them I know what objects I'm creating in my workspace - see the blog post of Gavin Simpson (linked in his answer) for a detailed discussion.

Comment: It works, except the function is called not 'loadRDS', but 'readRDS'. Thanks!

Comment: @user3276530 Oops, fixed now. If your issue has been resolved please consider accepting one of the answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: I'm getting `no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "tune"` error with the below  line of code: `svm.pred <- predict(get("svm.model"), testData[,-17])`, pls suggest.

Answer (score 5):

You misunderstand what `load` does. It restores an object to the same name it had when you `save()`d it. What you are seeing in `M` is the return value of the `load()` function. Calling `load()` has the additional side effect of loading the object back under the same name that it was saved with.

Consider:

```
require("e1071")
data(iris)

## classification mode
# default with factor response:
model <- svm (Species~., data=iris)
## Save it
save(model, file = "my-svm.RData")
## delete model
rm(model)
## load the model
M <- load("my-svm.RData")
```

Now look at the workspace

```
> ls()
[1] "iris"  "M"     "model"
```

Hence `model` was restored as a side effect of `load()`.

From `?load` we see the reason `M` contains the name of the objects created (and hence saved originally)

```
Value:

     A character vector of the names of objects created, invisibly.
```

If you want to restore an object to a new name, use `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()`:

```
saveRDS(model, "svm-model.rds")
newModel <- readRDS( "svm-model.rds")
ls()

> ls()
 [1] "iris"     "M"        "model"    "newModel"
```

If you want to know more about `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()` see the relevant help `?saveRDS()` and you might be interested in a [blog post I wrote on this topic](http://bit.ly/saveRDS).